# React Native: AwesomeProject not starting in emulator

Tags: react-native

I’m attempting to start up up the AwesomeProject basic project in react native, which is hanging when attempting to hit http://localhost:8081.

Currently, the iOS emulator is starting up properly by running

```
yarn ios
```

After a short period of time, I’m met with the red error screen everyone loves stating “Could not connect to development server.

Here are the current tool versions.

- Mac OS: 10.15.4 (macOS Catalina)
- NodeJS: v10.19.0
- yarn: 1.22.4
- npm: 6.13.4
- react-native cli: 3.2.1
- react-native npm bundle: 0.61.4
- expo: 3.15.5
- expo npm bundle: 36.0.0
- watchman: 4.9.0
- xcode: 11.4 (11E146)

I’ve tried numerous ideas such as:

- Trying to hit the 8081 url through the browser upon the emulator. I was able to hit the http url just fine
- Tried to clear all caches, remove node_modules folder, etc
- Ensured the OS firewall is disabled
- Upgraded to the latest version of Node

As this point, I'm completely stuck lol and need to get this silly app working.

Can anyone here recommend some ideas?

Comment: Did you get it to work?